# Unable to post an image to a Facebook page using PHP Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post as a Facebook page an image with text using the Facebook Graph PHP API.

The problem is that for some reason, the post was uploaded, but only with the text, the image wasn't uploaded.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$response = $fb->get('me/accounts', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
$response = $response->getDecodedBody();
print_r($response);

$pageId = $response['data'][0]['id'];

$arr = array(
    'message' => $_POST['POST_TEXT'],
    'image' => $target_dir,
    'to' => $pageId,
    'from' => $pageId
);
$res = $fb->post($pageId.'/feed/', $arr, $response['data'][0]['access_token']);
```

The `$target_dir` variable is the path for the PNG image, but for some reason, the post contains only the text.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can not post images with simple "status message only" feed posts, that is applicable only when you are sharing a link via the post, then you can specify a thumbnail. If you want to do an actual photo upload instead, then use the right endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/photos

Comment: @CBroe But I want to post an image with text. How can I do that?

Comment: Then set a `caption` while doing so ...